# Fix WSUS related DB bloating, Uninstall & Install issues on SBS Server 2008?

Tags: installation, database, wsus, windows-sbs-2008, uninstall

Environment: SBS Server 2008
DC/ Domain Server: Windows Server 2008 FE

- **Microsoft Windows Server Update Services 3.0 SP1 - MMC**
  SUSDB.MDF started at 14.x GB and when trying to use the Updates Cleanup options {will link more detail from an article we found to do that}, it would go on for a long time and then eventually crash and now the SUSDB.MDF file is 24.x GB

  Tried this a few times but it would crash again with no reduction in size.
- So we figured maybe uninstall "**Microsoft Windows Server Update Services 3.0 SP1**" and start fresh by reinstalling it or a more updated version.

  The uninstall was asking for a file in a `e:\..long guid like hex number..\...\..` location which was not at the said location nor any other drives or locations on the server.

  It closed with a uninstall not done properly.
- We were unable to delete the MDF files or perform any delete or reduction operations from the SQL Server Management Studio Express.
- We figured we could install the latest version: 3.0 SP2 from Microfost here: 
  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5216

  And after that try cleanup / uninstall, but this won't install as well, fails and points to the attached file log and there is no Program/ working MMC or Uninstall entry in Programs & Features.

So, what can we do now in such a scenario?

WSUS Install/ Setup Log file:

`C:/Users/administrator.COMPANY/AppData/Local/Temp/WSUSSetup.log

2016-05-03 13:41:42  Success   MWUSSetup          Validating pre-requisites...
2016-05-03 13:41:57  Success   MWUSSetup          Removing Wsus...
2016-05-03 13:55:48  Error     MWUSSetup          RemoveWsus: MWUS Uninstall Failed (Error 0x8007064C: The installation source for this product is not available. Verify that the source exists and that you can access it.)
2016-05-03 13:55:48  Error     MWUSSetup          Wsus MSI uninstallation failed. (Error 0x8007064C: The installation source for this product is not available. Verify that the source exists and that you can access it.)
2016-05-03 13:55:48  Error     MWUSSetup          CSetupDriver::LaunchSetup: Setup failed (Error 0x8007064C: The installation source for this product is not available. Verify that the source exists and that you can access it.)
2016-05-03 13:55:54  Error     MWUSSetup          DoInstall: Wsus setup failed (Error 0x8007064C: The installation source for this product is not available. Verify that the source exists and that you can access it.)
2016-05-03 15:05:54  Success   MWUSSetup          Validating pre-requisites...
2016-05-03 15:05:54  Error     MWUSSetup          WSUS is outdated. But this will not block setup (Error 0x00000000: The operation completed successfully.)
2016-05-03 15:05:56  Error     MWUSSetup          ExecuteQuery: Failed to execute SQL query USE SUSDB IF EXISTS (select * FROM master..sysdatabases WHERE name= N'SUSDB' AND suser_sname(sid) is null) EXEC dbo.sp_changedbowner N'COMPANY\administrator' (Error 0x80040E14)
2016-05-03 15:05:56  Error     MWUSSetup          ExecuteQueryGetNoResults: Failed to execute query USE %s IF EXISTS (select * FROM master..sysdatabases WHERE name= N'%s' AND suser_sname(sid) is null) EXEC dbo.sp_changedbowner N'%s' (Error 0x80040E14)
2016-05-03 15:05:56  Error     MWUSSetup          CUpgradeDriver::PerformPreSetupActions: Failed to reset database owner name for SUSDB to owner COMPANY\administrator (Error 0x80040E14)
2016-05-03 15:05:56  Error     MWUSSetup          CSetupDriver::LaunchSetup: Failed to perform pre-setup actions (Error 0x80040E14)
2016-05-03 15:05:56  Error     MWUSSetup          CProgressManager::EnableCancel: GetDlgItem returning error (Error 0x80070578: Invalid window handle.)`

Comment: You better start thinking of alternatives to SBS 2008 than fixing old software. SBS 2008 hits EOL in less than a year.

Comment: @Daniel - Yes, that is being worked on as well. But, lot of house cleaning to be done. There's SBS 2003, 2000, Win 95, DOS Apps and lot of legacy here.

Answer (score 1):

Several repeated attempts with 3.0 SP2 linked in the question and lots of SQL/ Regitry & Server/ IIS settings and nothing worked.

I must've read 100s of articles, blog posts and the downloaded SP2 would just not get installed despite lots of manual hacks / registry/ DB changes/ permissions / folder and file manipulations.

I will post more links of the things that did not work and what worked is below.

**Step 1: Reinstallation of WSUS 3.0 SP1 from SBS ISO:**

I was finally able to reinstall WSUS via the SBS ISO which contained WSUS 3.0 SP1.

The assumption that a later version of the same will work just as well or better was wrong.

**Step 2: Using Adamj's script for WSUS trimming:**

Once installed, I used the AdamJ's script from the link below for cleanup:

PS: I do not have copyright to this script so I am linking to it and quoting what it does.

> Have a peak at my Adamj Clean-WSUS script. It is the last WSUS Script
>   you will ever need.
>
> http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/2998-adamj-clean-wsus
>
> What it does:
>
> 1. Shrink your WSUSContent folder's size by declining superseded updates.
> 2. It will clean out all the synchronization logs that have built up over time (configurable, with the default keeping the last 14 days of
>      logs).
> 3. Remove all Drivers from the WSUS Database.
> 4. Remove declined updates from the WSUS Database
> 5. Run the server cleanup wizard.
> 6. Lastly, but most important, it will run the recommended maintenance script on the actual SQL database.
>
> It will email the report out to you or save it to a file, or both.
>
> Follow the instructions at the top of the script, but essentially run
>   .\Clean-WSUS.ps1 -FirstRun and then set a scheduled task to run the
>   script with the -ScheduledRun daily at a time you want.